# How to get hidden properties using forge API

Tags: autodesk-forge

I wanted to get hidden properties of the file using forge api. Currently i'm referring towards this API https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/metadata/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/ for getting properties of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, [GET {urn}/metadata/{modelGuid}/properties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/metadata/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/) doesn't support hidden properties according to our engineering team.

However, we're listening to our customers' voices. Could you share your use case with me? If you don't want to share it publicly, please send it to `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com` instead.

In addition, if your models are uploaded to BIM360 Docs (http://docs.b360.autodesk.com/) or Autodesk Docs (https://acc.autodesk.com/docs), you may use Model Properties API instead.

- https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/bim-360acc-model-properties-api
- https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/model-properties-api-vs-model-derivative-api
- API reference: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/index-v2-index-fields-get/